# How to boil down similar looking C# methods into a generic one

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, delegates

Is it possible to boil down the two methods in `Lane` into one generic function which can be reused by passing in the interface and method name? Or are there better ways to approach this problem?

---

Context: I'm making a rhythm game in which a music note is judged on key down and key up, currently I have the following interfaces and methods:

```
public interface IJudgeDown {
    public Judgement JudgeDown(double inputBeat);
}

public interface IJudgeUp {
    public Judgement JudgeUp(double inputBeat);
}
```

```
public class Lane {
    private bool CheckKeyDown(double inputBeat) {

        MusicNoteGameObject frontNote = visibleNotes.Peek();
        IJudgeDown downObj = (IJudgeDown)frontNote;
        Judgement j = downObj.JudgeDown(inputBeat);
        // ... (identical to the rest of CheckKeyUp)
    }

    private bool CheckKeyUp(double inputBeat) {

        MusicNoteGameObject frontNote = visibleNotes.Peek();
        IJudgeUp upObj = (IJudgeUp)frontNote;
        Judgement j = upObj.JudgeUp(inputBeat);
        // ... (identical to the rest of CheckKeyDown)
    }
}
```

The `MusicNoteGameObject` itself does not implement these two interfaces. However, this base class is extended for different note types which do implement the two interfaces (e.g., `TapNoteGameObject : MusicNoteGameObject, IJudgeDown, IJudgeUp`).

---

### Initial unsuccessful attempt:

```
public interface IJudge { }   // Have an empty interface
public interface IJudgeDown : IJudge { ... }
public interface IJudgeUp : IJudge { ... }

private bool Judge<I>(Func<double, Judgement> method, double inputBeat) where I : IJudge {

    MusicNoteGameObject frontNote = visibleNotes.Peek();
    I obj = (I)frontNote;   // This cast is invalid
    Judgement j = obj.method(inputBeat);   // How should I call the method on obj? Reflection?
    // ...
}
```

To pass in the correct method into `Judge<>`, I would have to cast `frontNote` outside of `Judge<>` like so:

```
MusicNoteGameObject frontNote = visibleNotes.Peek();
IJudgeDown downObj = (IJudgeDown)frontNote;
Judge<IJudgeDown>(downObj.JudgeDown, inputBeat);
```

but then I don't need to pass in `IJudgeDown` anymore, and I could wrap the rest of the `Judge<>` into a function and call it, making the `Judge<>` method unnecessary...

Answer (score 1):

You could consolidate into a single method like so:

```
public enum JudgeAction { Up, Down }
private bool CheckKey(JudgeAction action, double inputBeat) 
{
    var frontNote = visibleNotes.Peek();
    
    switch (action)
    {
       case JudgeAction.Down:
         var downObj = frontNote as IJudgeDown;
         downObj?.JudgeDown(inputBeat);
       break;
       case JudgeAction.Up:
         var upObj = frontNote as IJudgeUp;
         upObj?.JudgeUp(inputBeat);
       break;
    }
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding: your answer concatenates the two operations, `JudgeDown` and `JudgeUp`, but I want a sort of "master" method that replaces `CheckKeyDown` and `CheckKeyUp` by allowing these two methods to be derived from it. For example, `CheckKey<IJudgeDown>` would be the same as the current `CheckKeyDown`.

Comment: updated according to your feedback. Using generic types and interface hierarchies complicate things. Given the fact your frontNote implements both interfaces and you need to specify in a way or another the kind of judgeAction, I made the choice to use an enum which achieves this goal without further complicating your types and method signatures.

Comment: Using a switch case seems like a good compromise between complexity and convenience. The reason I wanted to have a generic `CheckKey` function is because when more types of `Judge...`s are implemented, I don't want to manually add code elsewhere to facilitate them. In other words, being able to write a new interface and its sole method without having to modify anything in `CheckKey...` is ultimately what I want, but thanks for the suggestion!